# How to use this javascript on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been getting help from some as to how I could fix the issue about how I want to be able to click a button, and have it instead auto select the search box on my site.

Well, people are telling me to use Javascript for the click to do it and I was told to use this code:

```
function setFocus() {
    document.getElementById("myTextbox").focus();
}
```

But I don't know how to properly combine it with my html. Looked around on Google and everything isn't piecing together for me..

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DLL Download Database</title>
<meta name="description" content="Need a .DLL file? Don't worry, I am sure we have a DLL available for you!">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus() { document.getElementById("search").focus(); }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="my_container cf">
    <div class="headerbuttons"><a href="http://dll-download.us/" style="text-decoration: none; color:#000000;padding:3px;display:block;"><p>HOME</p></a></div>
    <div class="headerbuttons"><a href=""style="text-decoration: none; color:#000000;padding:3px;display:block;"><p>HOW TO INSTALL</p></a></div>
    <div class="headerbuttons"><p style="text-decoration: none; color:#000000;padding:3px;display:block;" onClick="setFocus(search);">CAN'T FIND A FILE?</p></div>
    <div class="headerbuttons"><a href="http://www.dll-files.com/get-fixer/"style="text-decoration: none; color:#000000;padding:3px;display:block;"><p>DLL SOFTWARE FIXER</p></a></div>

</div>
<h2 class="homepage-start"><strong>WELCOME TO DLL DOWNLOAD.US!</strong></h2>
<div class="body-main2">
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search for a DLL" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add Onclick="setFocus()" on ur button click evnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make the following changes in your html

**HTML**

```
<div class="body-main2">
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
    <input id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search for a DLL"/>
</form>
</div>    


<div class="headerbuttons">
    <a style="text-decoration: none; 
    color:#000000;padding:3px;display:block;" onclick="setFocus();">
        <p>CAN 'T FIND A FILE?</p>
     </a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus() {
document.getElementById("searchbox").focus();
}</script>
```

Its working fine !!!  See this [working JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyjose009/ZLHLj/2/)

Comment: The only issue is that you have to actually click on the text. The usual padding does not work.

Comment: Apologies Tony, as you see, when you hover your mouse on the edges of the other tabs, you can see that it has the hyperlink selected. But on the Can't find file' tab, it's not like the others. Is there a work around for that?

Comment: I think you are asking about the cursor style ?

Comment: You have used <a> tag inside for all other tabs, but for the  Can't find file' tab you have used <p> tag, So my question is,  do you really want to use <a> tag  or You just need a cursor style change ?

Comment: I want to be able to click anywhere on the Can't Find File tab, not specific areas. Try clicking on edges and you can see it will not highlight the search box. If you click closer to the text it'll highlight it. I am trying to make the entire thing clickable. Please let me know if I need to re explain differently.

Comment: Hey.... 
   Please change the html

   <div class="headerbuttons"><a style="text-decoration: none; color:#000000;padding:3px;display:block;" onclick="setFocus();"><p>CAN'T FIND A FILE?</p></a></div>

Comment: Its working, I just replaced with this html in your site and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
onClick="javascript:setFocus();"  // no parameter
```

or more simply

```
onClick="setFocus();"  // no parameter
```

BTW, you should be setting the focus on the input tag not the `form`, so change the id of the input tag to be `id="search"` and of course remove it from the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling `setFocus(search)`

have you tried calling only `setFocus()`

in

```
`<div class="headerbuttons"><p style="text-decoration: none;color:#000000;padding:3px;display:block;"
onClick="setFocus(search);">CAN'T FIND A FILE?</p></div>`
```

EDIT:

remove `id = search` from the `form` element and set it on the `text` element

```
<form method="get" action="/search" >
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search for a DLL" id="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Makes no difference when clicking.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="setFocus(search);
```

remove "search" inside the braces

set `id="search"` for text field

Comment: OK, I just did that. It doesn't make a difference in how the button acts.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu2rg/)

You were not calling the function setFocus(). Also, there was no ID assigned to the textbox.

HTML:

```
<input name="q" id="search_box" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search for a DLL" />
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("search_box").focus();
```